# Best way to get as output an array with the first word in position 0 and others in position 1?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string

I need to know if I can make this code better and faster.

Example Input:

```
"hi my name is john cena"
```

Expected Output:

```
["hi", "my name is john cena"]
```

My code:

```
function getParams(query) {
    var keys = query.split(' ');
    var params = [];
    if(keys.length >= 2) {
        params.push(keys[0]);
        params.push("");
        for(var i = 1; i<=keys.length - 1; i++) {
            if(i != keys.length - 1) {     
                params[1] += keys[i] + " ";  
            }  else { 
                params[1] += keys[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return params;
}
```

Comment: How about `let [first, ...others] = query.split(' ')`?

Comment: so you need to split , after hi is that what you required. So the hi can come any where of the string , but you need to split it and get the hi as separate element in array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the magic of **[`rest`/spread syntax](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread)**, to construct your desired result `array`:

```
function getParams(query) {
  let [first, ...rest] = query.split(" ");
  return [first, rest.join(" ")];
}
```

**Explanation:**

- In the following code `first` will hold the first element from the
  resulting `array` of `query.split(" ")` and `rest` will hold the remaining
  `words/elements` of it.
- Then we return an `array` which contains `first` and the rest `array`
  joined as a `string` using `rest.join(" ")` to get the desired
  original remaining part of the `query` string.

**Demo:**

```js
let str = "hi my name is john cena";

function getParams(query) {
  let [first, ...rest] = query.split(" ");
  return [first, rest.join(" ")];
}

console.log(getParams(str));
```

Comment: i love this way!

Comment: @AlessandroBertozzi glad you like it ;)

Comment: `split` and then `join` is not the fastest way, but is more readable

Comment: @fanjabi May be it's not faster when we are dealing with a huge amount of words, but this is not the case ;)

Answer (score 1):

The [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method is very helpful here.

```
function getParams(x) {
    const index = x.indexOf(' ')
    return [x.slice(0, index), x.slice(index + 1)]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var text = "hi my name is john cena";

function getParams(query) {
  var idx = query.indexOf(' ');
  return [ query.substr(0, idx), query.substr(idx + 1) ];
};

console.log(getParams(text));
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can simply split the string in two parts based on the first occurrence of white space:

```js
let str = "hi my name is john cena";
let result = str.split(/\s(.+)/);
result.pop()
console.log(result);
```